# How to make OnLoad Event work for React Widget?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, widget, element, onload

I'm trying to call function once after component created with react.. I'm new in to this, so hope you can help me to understand. I tryied to put onLoad event in component creation, but it doesn't work. I tried to just put function call, but it's being called in the circle, but i need it to be called once - when component will finish to load.

Below is the function i got to create component and i want function 'handleClick' also to be called when component will be loaded.

```
function BadgeSample(props) {
    const {
      type,
      defaultValue,
      className,
      style,
      value,
      bootstrapStyle,
      clickable,
      onClickAction,
      getRef
    } = props;
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(false);
    const [pasuedd, setPasued] = React.useState(false);
    const [highlightSection, setHighlightSection] = React.useState({
      from: 0,
      to: 0
    });
    const synth = window.speechSynthesis;
    let utterance;
    const handleClick = () => {
      if (!synth) {
        console.error("no tts");
        return;
      }
      utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(value || defaultValue);
      utterance.addEventListener("start", () => setDisabled(true));
      utterance.addEventListener("end", () => setDisabled(false));
      utterance.addEventListener("boundary", ({
        charIndex,
        charLength
      }) => {
        setHighlightSection({
          from: charIndex,
          to: charIndex + charLength
        });
      });
      synth.speak(utterance);
    };
    const stoped = () => {
      synth.cancel(utterance);
    };
    const pasued = () => {
      setPasued(true);
      synth.pause(utterance);
    };
    const resumed = () => {
      setPasued(false);
      synth.resume(utterance);
    };

//handleClick(); - here it will work, but it will repeat itself in the loop and never stopped

    return React.createElement("div", {
      className: "App",
      onClick: onClickAction,
      onLoad: handleClick, // - here it doesn't work..
      ref: getRef,
      style: style
    }, React.createElement(HighlightedText, _extends$sj({
      text: value || defaultValue
    }, highlightSection)), React.createElement("button", {
      className: disabled ? "stopbtn" : "playbtn",
      onClick: disabled ? stoped : handleClick
    }, disabled ? React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement(StopCircleFill, null), "Stop") : React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement(PlayCircleFill, null), "Listen")), disabled ? React.createElement("button", {
      className: pasuedd ? "playbtn" : "pausebtn",
      onClick: pasuedd ? resumed : pasued
    }, pasuedd ? React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement(PlayCircleFill, null), "Resume") : React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement(PauseCircleFill, null), "Pause")) : "");
  }
```

I try to make one call of function after page with component will be loaded.. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use useEffect.
its the most efficiant way that i know and it's very comfortable to use.
its a function that you can decide when you call it, and you have an option to call it just once when your website renders the first time.

here's an example:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // your function here
  }, []);

  return (
    // your component's content and so...  );
};
```

and if you want it to be called when one of you states changes you can do that too.
I highly recommend you read about it and use it for your projects.
hope it helps :)